# A Riddle of Subtraction

Tags: riddle, word

You might have to use some creative thinking for this riddle.

Start with the one which has 4

> Take out the 7 and you end up with an 8.

Start with one which has 5

> Take out the 7 and you end up with a 4

Start with the one which has 4.

> Take out the 7 and you end up with a 2

Start with the one which has 5.

> Take out the 7 and you end up with a 1.

What am I starting with?  Four answers.

No partial answers please.

Hint

> What letter can be inverted to get a number

Comment: The last one definitely has 5?

Comment: Yes @Amoz. A bit trickey

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thinking along the same lines as Amoz but this time we use

> **L** instead of **G**, as per the hint ('L' being an inverted '7')

Start with the one which has 4.
Take out the 7 and you end up with an 8.

> This would be **L**ATE -> ATE

Start with one which has 5.
Take out the 7 and you end up with a 4.

> F**L**OUR -> FOUR

Start with the one which has 4.
Take out the 7 and you end up with a 2.

> TOO**L** -> TOO

Start with the one which has 5.
Take out the 7 and you end up with a 1.

> A**L**ONE -> A ONE

Comment: @Amoz was on the right track. But now you have it.

Answer (score 8):

Start with the one which has 4

> Start with GATE (has 4 letters)

Take out the 7 and you end up with an 8.

> Take out G (7th letter) and you end up with ATE

Start with one which has 5

> Start with FORGE (has 5 letters)

Take out the 7 and you end up with a 4

> Take out G (7th letter) and you end up with FORE

Start with the one which has 4.

> Start with TOGO (has 4 letters)

Take out the 7 and you end up with a 2

> Take out G (7th letter) and you end up with TOO

Start with the one which has 5.

> Start with [GONNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonne) (has 5 letters)

Take out the 7 and you end up with a 1

> Take out G (7th letter) and you end up with ONNE

> Which are all homophones of the specified numbers!

Comment: Great thinking. But the last one is a stretch.

Comment: rot13(Vf YBATR n fgergpu? Be vf guvf jubyr nafjre bss genpx?)

Comment: Lbh ner ba evtug genpx nf sne nf guvaxvat bs n yrggre. Vf gurer nabgure???

Comment: Jryy, fb sne nyy V unir vf NTBAR - T = "N BAR", ohg V nffhzr V arrq gb gnxr guvf n jubyr arj qverpgvba. Fgvyy guvaxvat....